# php echo and echo json_encode returns weird characters

Tags: php, ajax, json, mongodb

So I was developing something with PHP and MongoDB on windows with xampp, and I moved my php files to linux mint, it runs apache2 with php cgi 5.4.

After I moved my files (without changing) to linux, the php started returning these weird characters after every response.

```
echo 'success';
```

response comes like this

```
sucess����������������
```

when converted it looks like this

```
sucessï¿½
```

It seems like they are appended to the end of everything, here is a screenshot of responses with firebug (only left side of the pic)

[Link to the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbqjY.png)

Also mongod started echoing some errors that never existed on windows (right side of the picture for reference).

I do not use any special characters, languages, encodings, nothing of that sort.

Did anyone experience anything like this?

Comment: Check for any [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) characters in your file

Comment: Have you tried to exit after echo?

Comment: @steven if i do exit('whaat') the response is whaat����������������

Comment: @swapnesh it looks like its BOM characters but I tried sed to remove them, but still no change

Comment: @abdu I checked in your screenshot ..you are getting connection error as well..check whr the port is free or not..which u declared in your code

Comment: @swapnesh yeah I did not start mongo at that particular request, I opened new file with vim, tmp.php with one line which is echo '123'; but i still have the same weird characters

Comment: Is this reproducible with from a new PHP script written from scratch (avoid copy/pasting anything from the existing file to avoid hidden control characters)? Beyond the web server, does the issue show up in a CLI environment? Mongo's UTF-8 errors will show up when validating field names and indexed values, so it's possible those tainted values are coming from PHP. Attempting to reproduce similar MongoDB writes from the JS shell could narrow it down further, if memory/network IO corruption isn't out of the question.

Answer (score -1):

Mongo stores all strings as utf-8 and expects them to be delivered as such. Simply convert your data to utf-8 before getting it from mongo and you're set.

Comment: This problem happens even if I echo 'sucess', no data from mongodb at all.

Comment: I don't produce html, I echo back data (string/json string) with ajax